# Recommendations on baking sopes?

Tags: mexican-cuisine

The standard method of making [sopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sope) (and also [huaraches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huarache_(food)), chalupas*, and gorditas*) can be summed up as:

1. form medium-thick masa patties
2. griddle those on both sides on a dry griddle
3. form the raised edges of the sopes
4. let sopes cool
5. shallow-fry the sopes on both sides
6. add toppings and serve

[Sample instructions, here](https://www.mexicoinmykitchen.com/sopes-recipe/).

The problem with the shallow-frying is that it's a very messy step, and sometimes [you dip them in tomato sauce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZxXyvNhgc4), making the frying even messier.

I'm wondering if step (5) could be replaced by baking them in a very hot oven, and if so what the optimal combination of time, temperature, and oil would be.  I've found a few internet sources with oven-baked sopes, but none of them appear to be very well-tested.  Has anyone actually tried this, or something similar, and if so what was your experience?

(* the traditional Mexican dishes by this name, not the Taco Bell versions, which are quite different)

Comment: I've never tried it, but I'd brush or spray them with oil before baking.  You might even put them on a wire rack if you have a fan oven so that it's sort of like an air fryer.